# One domain for multiple Linux Servers

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, domain-name-system

I apologize in advance if the question I'll be asking is basic or anything but I am quite a newbie on this topic.

I have a main domain **example.com** which is used for the apache web server. Now I have another few Linux based servers which would be used as web and game servers for my customers. They could be accessed through **example.com/server1** or 
**example.com/server2**. Now what I'm asking is how could I go about setting that up? And how could I add these servers dynamically?

P.S. I am not asking about load balancing or anything like that, I just need URLs like the examples above that would point to these extra servers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set up one primary server with Apache or Nginx as reverse proxy that forwards URLS like `/server2` to server2.

That said, having specific host names for the customers (e.g. `customername.example.com`) is often a better solution - when useful, they could also use their domain name in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Like what Sven said, using user specific hostnames (like customername.example.com) is a better solution. It is much simpler to implement and (depending on your registrar/name server provider) the DNS entries can be updated dynamically.

Also, subdomain hostnames are easier to implement solution as you don't need to manage the reverse proxy, just the DNS entries for the servers.